# SVG does not display

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

The following SVG does not display, what is the problem? It should display with size 40x40px with a color.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="20 20 40 40" fill="#14cc9e">

<path d="M1096 301.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 10.96-.66c-.09-.7.16-1.42.66-1.93l4.58-4.58a2.7 2.7 0 0 1 2.12-.79 5.26 5.26 0 0 0 5.46-6.76l-3.17 3.17c-1.6.35-3.9-1.98-3.56-3.56l3.17-3.17a5.36 5.36 0 0 0-5.23 1.32 5.29 5.29 0 0 0-1.52 4.32c.05.67-.2 1.33-.67 1.81l-4.69 4.7c-.5.51-1.22.76-1.94.67a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-6.17 5.46zm3 .58l.7-2.63 2.63-.7 1.92 1.92-.7 2.63-2.63.7z"></path>

</svg>
```

Comment: please save this SVG code file as filename.svg extension & open it in adobe illastator. this might show you what the problem.

Comment: Your viewBox is completely off, your path's bounding box top left corner is at 1095,283.

Comment: @jcaron nailed it, but thankfully this is an easy enough fix: just change that `M1096 301.5` at the start of the path to something more sensible, like `M1 18.5` (and the `viewBox` to `0 0 40 40`) - whatever software generated that path used relative coordinates for everything else, so just placing the initial point correctly should resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `transform = 'translate (-1090 -275)`

The `fill` command works in the svg file header, but it's more correct to move it to the patch

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40"  style="border:1px solid red;"> 
<g transform="translate(-1090 -275)">
<path fill="#14cc9e" d="M1096 301.5 a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 10.96-.66c-.09-.7.16-1.42.66-1.93l4.58-4.58a2.7 2.7 0 0 1 2.12-.79 5.26 5.26 0 0 0 5.46-6.76l-3.17 3.17c-1.6.35-3.9-1.98-3.56-3.56l3.17-3.17a5.36 5.36 0 0 0-5.23 1.32 5.29 5.29 0 0 0-1.52 4.32c.05.67-.2 1.33-.67 1.81l-4.69 4.7c-.5.51-1.22.76-1.94.67a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-6.17 5.46zm3 .58l.7-2.63 2.63-.7 1.92 1.92-.7 2.63-2.63.7z">
</path> 
</g>

</svg>
```

To find  the image, it is convenient to use a frame that shows the boundaries of svg in the browser window.

```
style="border:1px solid red;"
```

After debugging, the frame can be removed.

- The second option

  You can also shift the image using parameters `min-x`, `min-y`  `viewBox="1090 275 40 40"`

```html
<svg  width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="1090 275 40 40"  > 

<path fill="#14cc9e" d="M1096 301.5 a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 10.96-.66c-.09-.7.16-1.42.66-1.93l4.58-4.58a2.7 2.7 0 0 1 2.12-.79 5.26 5.26 0 0 0 5.46-6.76l-3.17 3.17c-1.6.35-3.9-1.98-3.56-3.56l3.17-3.17a5.36 5.36 0 0 0-5.23 1.32 5.29 5.29 0 0 0-1.52 4.32c.05.67-.2 1.33-.67 1.81l-4.69 4.7c-.5.51-1.22.76-1.94.67a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-6.17 5.46zm3 .58l.7-2.63 2.63-.7 1.92 1.92-.7 2.63-2.63.7z">
</path> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the svg background color with fill. As far as I know this doesn't work. Try using property background-color instead.

Comment: While this is true, it's not the issue. The path itself will default to a black fill. As jcaron points out in a comment on the question, the path is just waaaay off the canvas.